# Moodle install on hosted linux: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting

Tags: moodle

I install (by Git) Moodle on hosted site and succesfully run `php /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/install.php` (which created dataroot directory as `/home/my_user/moodledata` and set it in `config.php`)

But when I try to open web, error appears:

```
$CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.
```

Rights for folder are 777.

Any help?

Edit: -------------------------------------------------------------

```
$d = dir(getcwd());

echo "Handle: " . $d->handle . "<br>";
echo "Path: " . $d->path . "<br>";

$d->close();
```

I put these lines above in `config.php` and discover, that real path is not `/home/my_user/moodledata` but `/nfsmnt/hosting1_1/c/6/c69f848b-e898-4268-be47-11de7fa8e5ac/my_user/moodledata/`

So I do a little hack to dataroot definition:

```
$CFG->dataroot = getcwd().'/../../moodledata';
```

And home page is open (but no css). Unfortunatelly any other page (like login) do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by regexp replacing:

```
$CFG->dataroot  = preg_replace("/(.*)(\/web\/moodle\/.*)/", "$1/moodledata", getcwd());
```